# Issues with Missing Districts in Indian Cities and Villages JSON - Seeking Solutions

Tags: laravel

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've been working with the Indian cities and villages JSON dataset available at https://github.com/pranshumaheshwari/indian-cities-and-villages for my project in Laravel. However, I've encountered an issue where some districts seem to be missing from the dataset.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem? If so, how did you address it? Are there alternative datasets or approaches to ensure comprehensive coverage of districts?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I hope this would help https://publicapis.io/indian-cities-api

Comment: I think you should also consider forking the repo and, adding what is missing and then make a pull request (you could use your fork in the meantime). That way you can help others too